# How to write this powershell code on cmd/bat?

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, scripting, cmd

How to write this powershell code on cmd/bat?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Pwd\text\*.txt" | ForEach-Object -Process 
{
    $filename = $_ | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Name
    Start-Process notepad.exe -ArgumentList $filename -Wait
}
```

Comment: Unless that -ExcludeProperty was supposed to be -ExpandProperty, this appears to be nonsense.

Comment: is this homework or what? what is the reason you need to do this translation?

Answer (score 1):

```
for %A in ("c:\somefolder\*.txt") do start "" /w notepad %A
```

Opens all text files in notepad one by one. Use %%A in a batch file and %A when typing at command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

To run powershell script from the command line you can do this:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "insert your code here"
```

e.g.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path ('{0}\text\*.txt' -f $Pwd) | ForEach-Object -Process { $filename = $_ | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Name; Start-Process notepad.exe -ArgumentList $filename -Wait;}"
```

Better, stick in into a `.ps1` file, then execute that:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File .\MyScript.ps1
```

NB: `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` is optional in the above posts; I tend to find it useful for most functions, but it's not always required.  Setting execution policy to unrestricted is considered bad practice, but if you write all your code yourself, should be fine.

- http://www.powertheshell.com/bp_noprofile/
- http://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html